# How to pass an object of a child class as a function argument?

Tags: c#

I would like to define a function that will work for passing objects of a certain class hierarchy without overloding it for every child class, only by defining it with a base class argument.

```
 public bool SendReceive(Request request, Response response){...}


 internal class Message
 {
     public int id;
 }

internal abstract class Request : Message {...}

internal class SystemSetTimeRequest : Request
{
     public long seconds;
     ...
}

internal abstract class Response : Message{...}

internal class SystemSetTimeResponse : Response
{
    public bool time_set;

    ...
}
```

When using the `SendReceive()` function with `SystemSetTimeRequest` and `SystemSetTimeResponse`, I can't access their additional members that are not defined in the base class.

Can I use generics that will work for a certain class hierarchy to get around this? What would be a practical solution that doesn't require repetitive code?

Comment: If you want to access it, you need to expose the property / method (preferably not field) from the base class (the type of the variable). Alternatively, use `as` to cast to the type you want (and be sure to `null` check it afterwards). Alternatively, consider using `dynamic`.

Comment: Is it possible to minimize/simplify the example? I thought I understood your question, but this was before I tried to read the code.

Comment: Use an interface, delegate common code to a helper class.

Comment: This isn't C++.  Return your response and throw exceptions.  As for your question your input or output types  should use an interface.  You can use filter generics if you need the output to match the original type from the callers point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for a solution, I could identify this problem as a need for **method overeloading**. For the purpose of using a function that can take  arguments from any class within a class hierarchy, I found **generics** with **constraints** to be one proper solution:

```
public bool SendReceive<Req, Resp>(Req request, ref Resp response) where Req : Request where Resp : Response
```